# Newbie to mysql, unable to understand

Tags: mysql, select, join

I need to find out how to do this...

For each book that has a either more than 17 copies or fewer than 5 copies among entire library system (not just one branch), display "title" and total number of copies as "total_copies".

> BOOK (book_id, title)
>   BOOK_COPIES (book_id, branch_id, no_of_copies)
>   LIBRARY_BRANCH (branch_id, branch_name, address)

I am unable to understand how to do this, whether I need to use sub-queries or plain single line queries?

Please help me understand...!!

Comment: Use "Joins", to read about Joins use following link [link] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Thanks 4 the link, it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT BOOK.book_id, BOOK.title, SUM(no_of_copies) 
FROM BOOK_COPIES 
INNER JOIN BOOK ON BOOK_COPIES.book_id=BOOK.book_id 
GROUP BY BOOK_COPIES.book_id 
HAVING SUM(no_of_copies)<5 OR SUM(no_of_copies)>17
```

This is what it does

It first checks your `BOOK_COPIES` table and sums up the number of copies for all the books based on their book id, then it attaches the title from `BOOK` table and then finally it checks if the number of copies are less than 5 or greater than 17, then it returns all such results.

Read about [**JOIN(s)**](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php) here, they are very interesting and helpful.

Comment: Its perfect, just *SELECT BOOK.book_id
but could you explain it to me...?

would be a great help...

Answer (score 0):

A SQL JOIN should work here.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

```
SELECT
 `BOOK`.`title`,
 COUNT(`BOOK_COPIES`.`no_of_copies`) as `total_copies`
FROM `BOOK_COPIES`
JOIN `BOOK` ON (`BOOK_COPIES`.`book_id` = `BOOK`.`book_id`)
GROUP BY `BOOK_COPIES`.`book_id`
HAVING 
 `total_copies` > 17 AND
 `total_copies` < 5
```

Now based on the very little information you gave, this may or may not work depending on the number of rows in `BOOK_COPIES` and `BOOK` tables. Along with how you have your indexes setup; that is if you have any indexes.

If this runs very slow you might want to break this down into two sql calls like so.

```
SELECT
 `book_id`,
 COUNT(`no_of_copies`) as `total_copies`
FROM `BOOK_COPIES`
GROUP BY `book_id`
HAVING 
 `total_copies` > 17 AND
 `total_copies` < 5
```

Use whatever language your comfortable with and push the list of book ids into the second query.

```
SELECT
 `book_id`,
 `title`
FROM `BOOK`
WHERE `book_id` IN (/* List of book ids from first query */)
```

Example:

```
WHERE `book_id` IN (123, 345, 678, 901)
```